# How to script a unique index with included columns using SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, smo, unique-index

I’m trying to use [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162557.aspx) library to script a table creation with a unique non-clustered index that contains [included columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx).

The sort of script I’d like it to generate would be similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testTable]
(
        [columnA] [int],
        [columnB] [int],
);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [myIndex] 
ON [testTable] (A) INCLUDE (B)
```

My problem is that SMO, when it tries to script a unique index with included columns, fails with the exception below. It seems that SMO thinks that any unique index I create on a table is to be generated using the ADD CONSTRAINT statement, instead of the CREATE INDEX. I believe this is why it fails, because included columns are only valid in indexes, not on constraints. This happens on both versions 12 and 13.

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.WrongPropertyValueException: Cannot define an included column on this index type.
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Index.IndexScripter.ScriptColumn(IndexedColumn col, StringBuilder sb)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Index.ConstraintScripter.ScriptColumn(IndexedColumn col, StringBuilder sb)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Index.IndexScripter.ScriptColumns(StringBuilder sb)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Index.IndexScripter.GetCreateScript()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Index.GetDDL(ScriptingPreferences sp, Boolean creating, Boolean tableCreate)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Index.ScriptDdl(StringCollection queries, ScriptingPreferences sp, Boolean notEmbedded, Boolean createStatement)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table.GeneratePkUkInCreateTable(StringBuilder sb, ScriptingPreferences sp, ICollection indexes, Boolean embedded)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table.GetTableCreationScript(ScriptingPreferences sp, StringBuilder sb)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table.ScriptCreate(StringCollection queries, ScriptingPreferences sp)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ScriptCreateInternal(StringCollection query, ScriptingPreferences sp, Boolean skipPropagateScript)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptCreateObject(Urn urn, ScriptingPreferences sp, ObjectScriptingType& scriptType)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptCreate(Urn urn, ScriptingPreferences sp, ObjectScriptingType& scriptType)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptCreateObjects(IEnumerable`1 urns)
>
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptUrns(List`1 orderedUrns)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.DiscoverOrderScript(IEnumerable`1 urns)
>
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptWorker(List`1 urns, ISmoScriptWriter writer)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.Script(SqlSmoObject[] objects, ISmoScriptWriter writer)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.Script(SqlSmoObject[] objects)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table.ScriptCreateInternal(StringCollection query, ScriptingPreferences sp)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()

This is the C# snippet I was using to debug the problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Database tmpDatabase = null;

        try
        {
            tmpDatabase = new Database(new Server("(local)"), "myTempDb");
            tmpDatabase.Create();

            // create my table
            Table table = new Table(tmpDatabase, "testTable");
            table.Columns.Add(new Column(table, "columnA", DataType.Int));
            table.Columns.Add(new Column(table, "columnB", DataType.Int));

            // create my unique index and add key and included column
            Index index = new Index(table, "myIndex") { IndexKeyType = IndexKeyType.DriUniqueKey };
            index.IndexedColumns.Add(new IndexedColumn(index, "columnA"));
            index.IndexedColumns.Add(new IndexedColumn(index, "columnB") { IsIncluded = true });
            table.Indexes.Add(index);

            try
            {
                table.Create();
                var lines = table.Script(new ScriptingOptions() { Indexes = true });
                foreach (var line in lines) 
                     Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                if (e.InnerException != null) 
                   Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (tmpDatabase != null) tmpDatabase.Drop();
        }
    }
```

What could I change in this code to make SMO create a unique non-clustered index with included columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
Index index = new Index(table, "myIndex") { IndexKeyType = IndexKeyType.DriUniqueKey };
```

to

```
Index index = new Index(table, "myIndex")
{
    IndexKeyType = IndexKeyType.None,
    IsUnique = true
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but it gives the error "Create failed for Table 'dbo.testTable'.
To accomplish this action, set property IndexKeyType.".

Comment: @andre, what if you also assign `IndexKeyType = IndexKeyType.None` in index definition, as stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.indexkeytype.aspx), `None` is used when _"index is based on a column with no key constraint"_.

Comment: you are right. Setting IndexKeyType to None and IsUnique to true did it! I was under the impression that None was the default value for the key type and I didn't think of setting it myself before. Thank you.